# LIVE SDK v5.3 & Window 8 - How to tell the difference between a user logged in with a Microsoft Account and user with a local account?

Tags: c#, winrt-xaml, windows-store-apps, live-sdk

I'm using the v5.3 Live SDK for a Windows 8 Store App (XAML/C#) and I have a question.

1. In my app, if the user is logged into Windows using a Microsoft
   Account, then I want to grab the firstname/lastname/Microsoft ID.
2. If they are logged in to Windows using a local account and haven't
   logged in to my app, then I want to show a 'Login' button, so they
   can enter their Microsoft account email/password.

I know how to do all that using the Live SDK, but my question is - how can I tell if the user is logged into Windows with a Microsoft account versus a Local Account that hasn't been logged in to the MS account?

I can use the following:

```
var idAuth = new OnlineIdAuthenticator();
return idAuth.CanSignOut;
```

but this will return false if either the 2 criteria above is true (and return true if the user is using a local account, but has logged in to my app using Microsoft account details).

In theory, if the above returns false, I can do the following:

```
LiveAuthClient authClient = new LiveAuthClient();
LiveLoginResult authResult = await authClient.LoginAsync(new List<string>() { "wl.signin" });
if (authResult.Status == LiveConnectSessionStatus.Connected)
  { //Get user info here }
```

The problem is that this works fine for a user logged into windows using a Microsoft Account - their info is picked up fine, but if it is a user logged into Windows with a local account, then it is going to show the Live Login screen in my app - at that point I don't want to do that, rather just show a logon button in my UI.

Anyone any ideas on how to tell the difference between the 2 criteria above?

Thanks in anticipation,
 Richard.

Comment: Bad form answering my own question I know, but I asked the same question on the MSDN forums and got the following answer. Posting here just in case anyone else is stuck on this...

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/f6946851-b495-45f6-95a4-eb3c2a004c0e](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/f6946851-b495-45f6-95a4-eb3c2a004c0e)

Comment: It's actually quite good form to answer your own question. The FAQ even advocates it. Add your post as an answer and select it as the selected answer so that future askers can find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up asking the same question on the MSDN forums and got an answer there, so I am posting it here just in case it helps anyone else.

[http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/f6946851-‌​b495-45f6-95a4-eb3c2a004c0e](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/messengerconnect/thread/f6946851-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bb495-45f6-95a4-eb3c2a004c0e)

Comment: Please always give a _full_ answer. Link-only answers are useless in the future. This one is already: I only see a blank page.